# BeautifulSoup element Parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Please tell me how to parse the `div ID` of the element `c15597187` or `href= " /catalog/15597187/detail. aspx?targetUrl=GP"`

```
<div id="c15597187" class="l_class">

<a class="ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card" href="/catalog/15597187/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
```

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import textwrap
import csv


def cprint(text, color='def'):
    str = ''
    fc = '\033['
    colors = {'def': '0m',
              'red': '91m',
              'under': '04m',
              'green': '32m',
              'blue': '94m',
              'cyan': '96m',
              'yellow': '93m',
              'magenta': '95m',
              'grey': '90m'
              }
    if color not in colors:
        print(str + fc + colors['def'] + text)
    else:
        if color == 'under':
            print(str + fc + colors['under'] + text)
        else:
            print(str + fc + colors[color] + text)
def parser(link):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    html = req.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    news = soup.find_all('div', class_='dtlist-inner-brand')

    for item in news:
        title = item.find('div', class_='dtlist-inner-brand-name').get_text(strip=True)
        price = item.find('div', class_='j-cataloger-price').get_text(strip=True)
        # #href = item.find('a', {'class': 'ref_goods_n_p'}).get('href')
        # #link = item.find('a', class_='ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card').get('href')
        # #href = soup.find_all('a', class_='ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card')[0]
        # href = item.find("div", {"id": "l_class"})
        # print(href)
        href = item.findAll("div", {"id": "c15597187"})

        print(title, end=" = ")
        print("\033[4m\033[37m\033[40m{}\033[0m".format(price))
        print(href)


x = "https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/knigi-i-kantstovary/kantstovary/bumazhnaya-produktsiya"
b = 1
for i in range(1):
    parser(x)
    b += 1
    x = "https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/knigi-i-kantstovary/kantstovary/bumazhnaya-produktsiya" + "?page=" + str(b)
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? What code have you written?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html1 = """
<div id="c15597187" class="l_class">

<a class="ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card" href="/catalog/15597187/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html1, 'lxml')  # u can use html.parser too
print(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': re.compile('.*')}))
```

**Output**

```
[<div class="l_class" id="c15597187">
<a class="ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card" href="/catalog/15597187/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
</a></div>]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how to parse only such values c15597187 on the page there are many such IDs, you should get the name price and id

Comment: id ok but where is name and price?

Comment: actually find_all method returns a list of data it will contain all div datas

Comment: I added all the parser code to the starting question             title = item.find('div', class_='dtlist-inner-brand-name').get_text(strip=True)
                     price = item.find('div', class_='j-cataloger-price').get_text(strip=True)